# Automount in Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, mount, automount

By default Ubuntu doesn't mount internal NTFS hard drives automatically. 
A fstab solution not working properly, because of conflicts with the "intelligent" mount system. If I add my hd in fstab and reboot - it will be mounted. But if I go to nautilus, open places panel and click eject button (unmount) and than click on hd again to mount it, I will get an error.

In 9.04 to solve this problem you need to modify hal rules in `/etc/hal/... preferences.fdi` in my case I modified it for only one drive.

```
<device>
−
<match key="storage.hotpluggable" bool="false">
−
<match key="storage.removable" bool="false">
<merge key="storage.automount_enabled_hint"  type="bool">false</merge>
−
<match key="storage.model" string="ST3250310NS">
<merge key="storage.automount_enabled_hint" type="bool">true</merge>
</match>
</match>
</match>
</device>
```

But this is not working in 9.10 - devs removed this function from hal to devkit-disk or udev? I don't know. 
Could you please tell me where automount rules are stored in 9.10? And how to create new rules, and what program controls automount in 9.10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution finally. 
Just add

```
gnome-mount -p Data(change it to your volume label)
```

to gnome startup applications. Now drive will be mounted at startup and you will be able to mount/unmount it without any errors.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude install ntfs-config
```

Open the program from System > Administration.
Choose the drives that you want to be automounted. Click Apply.
Make sure that "Enable Write Support for Internal Drives" and click OK.

Worked for me :)

Comment: This will add entry to fstab which is not working good. This is static rule, i am looking for hal like solution which worked in 9.04. You dont need to hack fstab for automount usb drives, same logic should work for hard drives i believe.

Comment: Well all I know is it worked fine for me in 9.10.

Comment: This solution will work in 10.04 too. Let me add a more detailed tutorial: 
http://www.hackourlives.com/auto-mount-windows-partitions-in-ubuntu-10-04-lucid/