# Ubuntu Automount by Label?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, automount, autofs

Ubuntu Server 9.10

I know that using the `mount` command, you can use `-L` to mount by label like so:

```
mount -L thelabel /media/themount
```

Is there any similar way to setup Automount / Autofs to mount by label name?

Comment: related (neither are autofs specific, so they may not be duplicates): http://superuser.com/questions/53978/ubuntu-automatically-mount-external-drives-to-media-label and http://superuser.com/questions/62483/automount-in-ubuntu-9-10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
mylabel    -fstype=ext3    :/dev/disk/by-label/mylabel
```

Comment: On centos, mylabel -fstype=ext3 :/dev/disk/by-partlabel/mylabel